# Round up to 5 or 10 to create a new df

Tags: python

```
data = [{'A':"JAN", "B": 1133.3, "C": 1150.0}, {'A':"FEB", "B": "1133.3", "C": 1140.0}, {'A':"MAR", "B": "1133.3", "C": 1150.0}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a new df with next conditions:

- Select the row where "C = B round up to 5" *(C = 1135.0)*
- If it doesn´t exist (that´s the case), select the row where "C = B round up to 10" *(C = 1140.0)*

I´ve tried:

```
def roundup5(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 5.0)) * 5
i = float(roundup5(df.values[0][1]))

def roundup10(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10
v = float(roundup10(df.values[0][1]))

if (df["C"] == i) is False:
    print (df.loc[df["C"] == v])
else:
    print (df.loc[df["C"] == i])
```

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do here - you want to make a new column where B is rounded to 5? But if B doesn't exist how can you round it to 10? Please elaborate

Comment: Ok. I´ve edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use dataframe subsets to select all the rows where B rounded to 5 is equal to C, or where B rounded to 10 is == C.

```
data = [{'A':"JAN", "B": 1133.3, "C": 1150.0}, {'A':"FEB", "B": 1133.3, "C": 1140.0}, {'A':"MAR", "B": 1133.3, "C": 1135.0}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def roundup5(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 5.0)) * 5

def roundup10(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10

df_round5 = df[df['C']==df['B'].apply(roundup5)]
df_round10 = df[df['C']==df['B'].apply(roundup10)]
```

Comment: My last C column is "1150.0", not "1135.0". What I´m trying to obtain is just one df, selecting the rows where B rounded to 5 is equal to C, and if it is not possible this condition (such as it happens in my df), then select the rows where B rounded to 10 is equal to C.

Comment: Right, I changed the last C column just for testing, since otherwise you wouldn't have any rows equal to B rounded to 5. Alternatively you can make the dataframe rounded to 5 as I have, check if it's empty (len(df)==0), then make the 10 rounded one. The real key is the dataframe subsetting syntax I've shown